# Object delete itself from container

Tags: c++, containers

So I have a container(any kind, probably std::map or std::vector) which contains objects of a class with some network thing running in a thread that checks if it is still connected (the thread is defined inside that class and launches when constructed).

Is there any way I can make the object delete itself from the container when its disconnected or should I move the thread outside the object and use that class just to store data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have am unload queue.

When a thread notices that the connection is down it registers the object (and continer) with the unload queue tides everything up as much as possible then the thred terminates.

A separate thread is then inside the unload queue. Its sole purpose is to monitor the queue. When it sees a new object on the queue, remove it from the container and then destroy it (syncing with the objects thread as required).

Comment: I don't really understand what an unload queue means but I used something similar;

Comment: A job queue (I use the term unload as you are unloading the object from a container). You just place a job on a queue (In this case the job is to unload/delete an objet from a container). A separate thread then processes the jobs one at a time.

Answer (score 7):

In order for the object to delete itself from the container, it will have to know which container it is in. You will need to maintain a pointer to the container in the object. You will also have to protect the container with a lock to stop multiple threads accessing the container at the same time.

I think I prefer your second solution - some managing object looks after removing dead objects from the collection. If nothing else, this will be quite a bit easier to debug and the locking logic becomes centralised in a single object.

Answer (score 1):

STL containers tend to assume they're storing values; objects that can be copied and where copies are identical. Typically, objects which have threads fit poorly into that model. They have a much stronger sense of identity. In this case, you definitely have indentity - a copy of the object in a container is distinct from a copy outside.

Comment: "Tend to assume"?
The assume or they don't assume that the objects stored are values: they aren't human beings!

Comment: STL containers ONLY store values. Those values may, of course, be pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem very similar to yours, which I solved by emitting a *boost::signal* from the "network thing" when it detected the disconnection, being caught by the object managing the container. Upon receiving that signal, it would iterate through the container, removing the dead network session from it. It might be worth looking at it here:

[How to make a C++ boost::signal be caught from an object which encapsulates the object which emits it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149391/how-to-make-a-c-boostsignal-be-caught-from-an-object-which-encapsulates-the)

Cheers,

Claudio