# How to make a C++ boost::signal be caught from an object which encapsulates the object which emits it?

Tags: c++, boost, containers, boost-signals

I have a **TcpDevice** class which encapsulates a TCP connection, which has an *onRemoteDisconnect* method which gets called whenever the remote end hangs up. Then, there's a **SessionManager** object which creates **TcpSession** objects which take a  **TcpDevice** as a communication channel and inserts them in an internal pointer container for the application to use. In case any of the managed **TcpSessions** should end, I would like the **SessionManager** instance to be notified about it and then remove the corresponding session from the container, freeing up the resources associated with it.

I found my problem to be very similar to this question:

[Object delete itself from container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/862093/1007502)

but since he has a thread for checking the connections state, it gets a little different from mine and the way I intended to solve it using *boost::signals*, so I decided to go for a new question geared towards it - I apologize if it's the wrong way to do it... I'm still getting the feel on how to properly use S.O. :)

Since I'm kind of familiar with QT signals/slots, I found **boost::signals** offers a similar mechanism (I'm already using *boost::asio* and have no QT in this project), so I decided to implement a ***remoteDeviceDisconnected*** signal to be emitted by **TcpDevice's** *onRemoteDisconnect*, and for which I would have a slot in **SessionManager**, which would then delete the disconnected session and device from the container.

To initially try it out I declared the signal as a public member of **TcpDevice** in *tcpdevice.hpp*:

```
class TcpDevice
{
             (...)
  public:
    boost::signal <void ()> remoteDeviceDisconnected;
             (...)
}
```

Then I emitted it from **TcpDevice's** *onRemoteDisconnect* method like this:

```
remoteDeviceDisconnected();
```

Now, is there any way to connect this signal to my **SessionManager** slot from ***inside*** session manager? I tried this:

```
unsigned int SessionManager::createSession(TcpDevice* device)
{
  unsigned int session_id = session_counter++;
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(sessions_mutex);
  sessions.push_back(new TcpSession(device, session_id));
  device->remoteDeviceDisconnected.connect(boost::bind(&SessionManager::removeDeadSessionSlot, this));
  return session_id;
}
```

It compiles fine but at link time it complains of multiple definitions of *remoteDeviceDisconnected* in several object code files:

```
tcpsession.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `remoteDeviceDisconnected'
tcpdevice.cpp.o: (.bss+0x0): first defined here
sessionmanager.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `remoteDeviceDisconnected'
tcpdevice.cpp.o: (.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

I found this strange, since I didn't redefine the signal anywhere, but just used it at the *createSession* method above.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! Like we all should expect, the linker was right... there was indeed a second definition, I just couldn't spot it right away because it wasn't defined by any of my classes, but just "floating" around one of my .cpp files, like those found on [*boost::signals* examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3137144).

Just for the record, the initial idea worked like a charm: when a given **TcpDevice** gets disconnected from the remote end, it emits the *remoteDeviceDisconnected* signal, which is then caught by the **SessionManager** object which holds the **TcpSession** instance that points to that **TcpDevice**. Once notified, *SessionManager's* method **removeDeadSessionSlot** gets executed, iterating through the *sessions* **ptr_list** container and removing the one which was disconnected:

```
void SessionManager::removeDeadSessionSlot()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(sessions_mutex);
  TcpSession_ptr_list_it it = sessions.begin();
  while (it != sessions.end()) {
    if (!(*it).device->isConnected())
      it = sessions.erase(it);
    else
      ++it;
  }
}
```

Hope that may serve as a reference to somebody!