# Can an object erase itself from a standard C++ container?

Tags: c++, containers, undefined-behavior

The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct foo
{
  void kill(std::map<int, foo>& m, int i)
  {
    m.erase(i);
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::map<int, foo> m;

  m.emplace(1, foo() );

  std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;

  m[1].kill(m, 1);

  std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
}
```

compiles without warning (g++), executes without error and judging by the output the `kill` method erases the `foo` object from the map. However, I feel that this might actually be undefined behavior. It seems that in the `kill` method after the line `m.erase(i)` `this` no longer points to a valid object.

What does the C++ standard say about this?

Comment: Yes it can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862093/object-delete-itself-from-container

Comment: Basically same principle as [`delete this;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3150942/2069064)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you enter your `kill`, `m[1]` (from `m[1].kill(m, 1);`) statement has been fully evaluated as being the `foo` object you are calling `kill` on.

Then you do `m.erase(i);` ending up destroying the current object `foo`.

As far as you write absolutely no statement using the current object (`this`) before you return from the `kill` function, that's perfectly acceptable and safe (as commented by the posts referenced by [Auriga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862093/object-delete-itself-from-container) and [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this)). Even if the current object does not exist anymore, your function will return safely from the stack, no reason for it to fail as far as I know.

As an illustration, this would end up with undefined behaviour and must NOT BE DONE:

```
struct foo
{
  void kill(std::map<int, foo>& m, int i)
  {
    m.erase(i);
    cout << attribute; // don't do that! current foo object does not exist anymore
  }
  int attribute;
};
```

So let's say what you are doing is risky, but valid and safe if you do it well.

As an illustration, this would end up with defined behaviour and CAN BE DONE:

```
struct foo
{
  void kill(std::map<int, foo>& m, int i)
  {
    int theAttribute = attribute;
    m.erase(i);
    cout << theAttribute; // OK!
  }
  int attribute;
};
```

Having a method delete the current object is probably not a good practice anyway (specially if another developer modifies the code later...he could easily make it crash with the first example above). At least put an explicit comment in the code to tell the current object could have been destroyed (note that `kill` could destroy the current object, another one, or none...depending on `m` content and `i`):

```
struct foo
{
  void kill(std::map<int, foo>& m, int i)
  {
    m.erase(i);
    // careful! current object could have been destroyed by above statement and may not be valid anymore! Don't use it anymore!
  }
};
```

Answer (score -4):

This isn't safe at all. `m.erase(i)` will avoid trying to erase the same object if called multiple times, but `m[1].kill(m, 1)` is undefined behavior if called more than once. In order to be slightly safer, `m.at(1).kill(m, 1)` will throw an `out_of_range` error.

Comment: Is my answer wrong or are people just DV happy today?

Comment: @StoryTeller Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. It illustrates that `m[1]` is no longer valid.

Comment: It's not even undefined behavior if called more than once... `m[1]` would first insert a new object, which would immediately get erased.

Comment: @user6279021: "`m[1]` is no longer valid", false: that's always valid...even if it does not necessarily return always the same object...